Confusion about definition of $I(X)$
I have a definition that states for $X\subset Spec(A)$ (where $A$ is some commutative ring with unity), define $I(X) = \{a\in A\ |\ a(p)=0,\ \   \forall p\in X\}$. I'm confused about what this really means, and I've seen other definitions online stating $$I(X) = \bigcap_{p\in X}p$$
I would appreciate if anyone can help me understand what this definition means. Thank you!

$a(p) = 0$ means that $\overline{a} = 0$ in $A/p$, i.e., $a \in p$. So the two definitions are equivalent.

Thank you! I realize I didn't know what $a(p)$ meant.
